# rails skip records that are addressed by named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a scope which uses a where clause to narrow the results down to records where a specific parameter is defined.

In Post.rb

```
scope :nav, where( "priority IS NOT NULL" )
```

Im using this scope to populate the site navigation with specific Posts.  However, the index controller action needs to omit these records.  Is there a way I can use the same named scope to omit these records from my index action?  Or do I need to write a second scope which is the inverse of the first?

```
def index
  @posts = Post.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Post.rb

```
scope :nav, ->(not_null = true) { not_null ? where.not(priority: nil) : where(priority: nil) }
```

In controller:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.order(created: :desc).nav(false)
end
```

Work in Rails 4.